# 3Ds Max and BIP skeleton modification

Tags: 3dsmax

In purpose of 3D modeling I'm using BIP skeleton. Is there any way to modify existing skeleton, i.e. increasing leg's length or so on?
I have been trying to increase it, but all parts of the skeleton increase simultaneously
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into 'figure' mode,
You find the menu at 'motion' panel, press the button for 'figure mode' there, then you can edit individual bones by using for example the regular 'scale' tool.

Comment: Thank you Stig. You answer was very useful :-).
Actually it was not my but my son's question and he send thank you to you :-)